# Checkbox click function not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

I have a group of checkboxes with same name. One textbox is associated with each checkbox. On page load, I am disabling all the textboxes. On click of each checkbox, the textbox corresponding to the checkbox should be enabled.

The problem is that, I tried with different codes to enable the textbox on checkbox click. But the checkbox click function is not working.

The code is as given below (I am using MVC framework):

```
{loopstart:setting:100}
 {if($setting%2==0)}
 <tr height="30">
 {endif}
 <td align="left">          
 <input type="checkbox" name="settingcheck" id="setting{$setting[0]}" value="{$setting[0]}"/>{$setting[1]}
</td>                                                   <td>                                                

<input type="text" size="2px" id="text{$setting[0]}">                                               


</td>

                                                {if($setting%2==1)}
                                                <td>&nbsp;</td> 
                                                {endif}     
                                    {loopend:setting}
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("INPUT[type=text]").prop("disabled",true); 
    $("INPUT[type=text]").css("background-color", "#ccc");

});
```

This code is for disabling all textboxes on page load and is working fine.

```
$('input[name='settingcheck']:checked').click(function() {

}
```

I wrote the above function for enabling the text box on corresponding checkbox click. But this function is not working. I tried alerting some text in this function.

Is there any problem in the code. Can anyone help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out the syntax highlighting. Does `settingcheck` look like a variable color or a string color? ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your string literal is not properly formed: since you have used `''` to enclose the literal all occurrences of `'` within the string have to be escaped(`'input[name=\'settingcheck\']:checked'`) or you can use `""` instead

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[name="settingcheck"]', function() {
    if(this.checked){
        //this is checked now
    } else {
        //this is unchecked now
    }
});
```

Comment: I have already tried this code many times. It is not working for me.

Comment: @Jenz looks like you are using a template to generate the elements... so they are dynamic in nature... you may have to try event delegation

Answer (score 1):

If not already checked you can try this

```
$('input[name="settingcheck"]').click(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        alert('checked');
    }
})
```

see [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/har1236/G4wqe/)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('input[name="settingcheck"]:checked').click(function() {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("input[name='settingcheck']:checked").click(function() {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('input[name="settingcheck"]:checked').on('click',function() {

});
```

OR

```
$(document).on('click', 'input[name="settingcheck"]:checked', function() {

});
```

OR

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[name="settingcheck"]', function() {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Tmeu9/)

> You can try like this :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" onclick="checkBoxClicked1(this)" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" style="display: none">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" onclick="checkBoxClicked1(this)" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" style="display: none">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

> Javascript:

```
 function checkBoxClicked1(checkbox) {
        debugger;
        var a = $(checkbox).is(':checked');
        var textBox = $(checkbox).closest("tr").children()[1].children[0];
        if (a) {
            $(textBox).show();
            $(checkbox).prop("checked", true);
        } else {
            $(textBox).hide();
            $(checkbox).prop("checked", false);
        }

    }
```